# Different actions on listview click at appwidget

Tags: android, listview, android-appwidget

I have appwidget with listview. Each listview item have different child views. I want, that on click some views I get event in my widget provider, and another views click: open activity. I can set events only on open activity or on get event in broadcast receiver, but not both. How I can todo this?

At first I set [setPendingIntentTemplate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setPendingIntentTemplate%28int,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) for listview at widget view. Next on bind item at listview in `RemoteViewsFactory` I set [setOnClickFillInIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setOnClickFillInIntent%28int,%20android.content.Intent%29).

But in `setPendingIntentTemplate` I can set [PendingIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html), generated from [getBroadcast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getBroadcast%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int%29) or [getActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getActivity%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int%29).

Ofcouse, I can use for all child item views use `PendingIntent` from broadcast.But then how I can open activity on receive event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I use for all child views at listview item only broadcast receiver events. If for some views I need open activity, then use application context and flag [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)